# Rails 3: getting an "undefined method `average_rating' for nil:NilClass"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nomethoderror

I put

```
  def average_rating
      @value = 0
      self.ratings.each do |rating|
          @value = @value + rating.value
      end
      @total = self.ratings.size
      @value.to_f / @total.to_f
  end
```

in my "msg.rb" and put

```
    <div id="avg_rating">
        <%= @msg.average_rating %>
    </div>
```

in the view home/_msgs_list.html.erb

I dont fully understand how the def average_rating method works (I copied the code from [here](http://eighty-b.tumblr.com/post/1569674815/creating-an-ajaxified-star-rating-system-in-rails-3)), so I am getting a nomethoderror for nil:nilclass. Can someone please help? Thanks.

Comment: Can you [gist](https://gist.github.com/) the stack trace?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem isn't (necessarily) with `average_rating`. It's that `@msg` isn't defined at all!

Make sure the controller for your view is defining your `@msg` properly.

If you have a situation where the `@msg` might or might not exist (and this is supposed to happen), you can avoid the error by doing something like:

```
<%= @msg.try(:average_rating) %>
```

or a simple `if` statement:

```
<%= @msg.average_rating if @msg %>
```